# How to get count before limit in the Mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, count, limit, aggregation-framework

In the following query:

```
db.orders.aggregate([{ $match : { status: "A"}, { $limit: 5} }]);
```

How can I get the count of documents after the `$match` but before the `$limit` is applied?

I still want to return an array of 5 documents. But if I use `$group` it seems that it would not preserve the array of documents. Can this be done in one call, or do I have to make two calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now you have to make two calls, one call with the $limit operator for your results followed by a second call for the count.  You could use the aggregation framework without the $limit operator and with a $group operator to calculate a count or as wdberkeley points out you can pass your criteria to .count() to get a count instead of using the aggregation framework if you are using a single match stage.

See [MongoDB - Aggregation Framework (Total Count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767580/mongodb-aggregation-framework-total-count).

Comment: Use [.count()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) to count the total number of results.

Comment: @wdberkeley with aggregate it doesn't work. You have to make two calls, like Brantino said

Comment: Beware that if you use `.count()`, then duplicate results will be counted that might have been eliminated by $group in your aggregate call.

Answer (score 32):

Starting in `Mongo 3.4`, the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) aggregation stage allows processing multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents:

```
// { "status" : "A", "v" : 3 }
// { "status" : "B", "v" : 14 }
// { "status" : "A", "v" : 7 }
// { "status" : "A", "v" : 5 }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $match: { status: "A"} },
  { $facet: {
      count:  [{ $count: "count" }],
      sample: [{ $limit: 2 }]
  }}
)
// {
//   "count" : [ { "count" : 3 } ],
//   "sample" : [ { "status" : "A", "v" : 3 }, { "status" : "A", "v" : 7 } ]
// }
```

This:

- starts by `match`ing documents whose `status` is `A`.
- and then produces via a `$facet` stage two fields that out of two distinct aggregation pipelines:

  - `$count` that simply provides the number of documents resulting from the preceding `$match` stage.
  - `sample` that is a `$limit`ed extract of documents resulting from the preceding `$match` stage.

Comment: I am prohibited from doing this because my pipeline uses a mongoDB Atlas search stage

Comment: The issue with using `$facet` is it returns _a single document_. Although it contains a list of documents, this document itself, like other documents in mongodb, is limited to 16MB. The `$limit` can be used to limit its size, though a single document in the response may violate it.
Therefore, if you suspect the result may exceed 16MB, the best way is to query twice.

Answer (score 4):

This can now be done in one call as of version 3.4 with the `$facet` aggregation. See here for an example: [Mongo aggregation with paginated data and totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111369/mongo-aggregation-with-paginated-data-and-totals)

Answer (score -2):

Another option is to limit the results at the application layer instead of in the Mongo query. Then you can get a count of the full result and you don't have to make two calls.

For example, in Python you would do:

```
data = db.orders.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "status": "A"} }])['result']
count = len(data)
data = data[skip:skip+limit]
```

If you have a complicated aggregate call on a large dataset, this is significantly faster than making two calls.

Comment: If the dataset is very large it might not fit in memory - that's why you can get a streaming cursor instead of loading all the result set in the application server memory. Moreover, executing to counting operation by the db server would save time for your application server to do something else.