# Mongo aggregation with paginated data and totals

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've crawled all over stack overflow, and have not found any info on how to return proper pagination data included in the resultset.

I'm trying to aggregate some data from my mongo store. What I want, is to have something return:

```
{
  total: 5320,
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 10,
  data: [
    {
      _id: 234,
      currentEvent: "UPSTREAM_QUEUE",
      events: [
        { ... }, { ... }, { ... }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: 235,
      currentEvent: "UPSTREAM_QUEUE",
      events: [
        { ... }, { ... }, { ... }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
// page and pageSize are variables
db.mongoAuditEvent.aggregate([
  // Actual grouped data
  {"$group": {
    "_id" : "$corrId", 
    "currentEvent": {"$last": "$event.status"}, 
    "events": { $push: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  // Pagination group
  {"$group": {
    "_id": 0,
    "total": { "$sum": "corrId" },
    "page": page,
    "pageSize": pageSize,
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "currentEvent": "$currentEvent",
        "events": "$events"
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$sort": {"events.timestamp": -1} }, // Latest first
  {"$skip": page },
  {"$limit": pageSize }
], {allowDiskUse: true});
```

I'm trying to have a pagination group as root, containing the actual grouped data inside (so that I get actual totals, whilst still retaining `skip` and `limits`).

The above code will return the following error in mongo console:
`The field 'page' must be an accumulator object`

If I remove the `page` and `pageSize` from the pagination group, I still get the following error:

> BSONObj size: 45707184 (0x2B96FB0) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: id: 0

If I remove the pagination group alltogether, the query works fine. But I really need to return how many documents I have stored `total`, and allthough not actually necessary, `page` and `pageSize` would be nice to return as well.

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or tell me if it is at all possible to do this in one go?

Comment: What do you mean by *it will not work*? Error? Unexpected results? Which part of query fails?

Comment: Added the error message as edit above

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you have a lot of events, {$ push: "$$ ROOT"}, will make Mongo return an error, I have solved it with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) (Only works with version 3.4+)

```
aggregate([
    { $match: options },
    {
      $facet: {
        edges: [
          { $sort: sort },
          { $skip: skip },
          { $limit: limit },
        ],
        pageInfo: [
          { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
        ],
      },
    },
  ])
```

Comment: why are you setting `_id: null`? Great answer tho, thank you

Comment: Why is $count not used? It's also 3.4+. Are there performance issues?

Comment: @insivika _id: null aggroup all match, you can use _id: "any string" too.

Comment: This won't work if your match returns 10 results and your skip is 100. If I am on page 2 of a list and I search for something, you will have to reset the skip to 0. 
Just a quick thing I saw, could be what you want

Answer (score 5):

A **performance optimization** tip:

When you use `$facet` stage for pagination, **Try to add it as soon as it's possible.**

For example: if you want to add `$project` or `$lookup` stage, add them after `$facet`, not before it.

it will have impressive effect in aggregation speed. because `$project` stage require MongoDB to explore all documents and get involve with all fields(which is not necessary).

Answer (score 3):

Did this in two steps instead of one:

```
// Get the totals
db.mongoAuditEvent.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$corrId"}}, {$group: {_id: 1, total: {$sum: 1}}}]);

// Get the data
db.mongoAuditEvent.aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id : "$corrId", 
    currentEvent: {"$last": "$event.status"}, 
    "events": { $push: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$sort: {"events.timestamp": -1} }, // Latest first
  {$skip: 0 },
  {$limit: 10}
], {allowDiskUse: true}).pretty();
```

I would be very happy if anybody got a better solution to this though.

Comment: Doesn't this break past 2.4 mongo?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/

Comment: This issue with this kind of group is that you may well end up building too large of a document (> 16Gb)