# How to implement Cursor based pagination for mongodb in node.js using official mongodb client when _id is overrided?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I want to implement pagination for [mongodb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) in [node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) enviroment using [offical mongodb package](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/).

I have mongodb collection whose rows are like
`db.registrations.findOne()`

```
{ "_id" : {"mtid" : 156568417304061, "uid" : 156568728002501}, "tid" : 2 }
```

Here `_id` is not instance of ObjectId() nor numeric. How can I implement Cursor based pagination on this collection? I will avoid `offset-based` and `time-based` pagination.
I treid to use idea given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411020/1762051 but I guess this will not fit in my case as `_id` is not numeric.

Comment: For pagination, I suggest to use Mongodb-aggregation. that's much more fast and flexible.
like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111369/mongo-aggregation-with-paginated-data-and-totals/59247367

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have much to do.

You have by default an index on `_id` and according to [mongodoc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/), the field you index can be a whole embedded document whose (sub) fields **order** matters.

That is `{mtid, uid}` is your embedded document and as long as you query in the same (sub)field order you should be fine.

You would then just need to sort by `_id`.

generate some data:

```
arr = Array(25).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i).sort(x=>Math.random()-0.5).map(x=>[(x-x%5)/5,x%5])
arr.forEach(([mtid, uid],i)=>db.dums.insert({_id:{mtid, uid},n:i}))
```

in my case:

```
{ "_id" : { "mtid" : 2, "uid" : 4 }, "n" : 0 }
{ "_id" : { "mtid" : 2, "uid" : 2 }, "n" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "mtid" : 0, "uid" : 1 }, "n" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "mtid" : 0, "uid" : 0 }, "n" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "mtid" : 0, "uid" : 2 }, "n" : 4 }
{ "_id" : { "mtid" : 2, "uid" : 3 }, "n" : 5 }
{ "_id" : { "mtid" : 3, "uid" : 1 }, "n" : 6 }
...
```

consider below query

```
function query(str){
  let [mtid, uid] = str.split('_')
  mtid = parseInt(mtid)
  uid = parseInt(uid)

  const res = db.dums.find({
    _id: {
      $gt: { mtid, uid }
    }
  }).limit(2).sort({ _id: 1 }).toArray()

  if(!res.length) return {items:[], next:null}
  const last = res[res.length-1]._id
  const next = last.mtid + '_' + last.uid
  print(res.map(x=>x._id.mtid+'_'+x._id.uid).join(';'))
  return {
    items: res,
    next,
    goNext(){return query(next)}
  }
}
```

results:

```
> var a=query('0_0');
0_1;0_2
> var a=a.goNext();
0_3;0_4
> var a=a.goNext();
1_0;1_1
> var a=a.goNext();
1_2;1_3
> var a=a.goNext();
1_4;2_0
> var a=a.goNext();
2_1;2_2
```

we can observe that the items are indeed ordered by mtid, uid